# Wpf login session

Tags: c#, wpf, session, sample

I know that "session" doesnt exist in WPF, but do you know any example codes for having a session in wpf? I actually want to save only one string and possibility to take/change that string from any windows in my wpf app.
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You may put your string in

```
Application.Current.Properties
```

You may look at the following article: [Storing Application-wide Data in WPF](http://msmvps.com/blogs/siva/archive/2007/05/11/storing-application-wide-data-the-wpf-way.aspx)

Comment: Hmm i have just tried it like that:
Application.Current.Properties.Add(1, whoIs); (whois is string) in one window, but in another i cannot read it (tried to read like that:         
Application.Current.Properties[1])

Comment: its a dictionary, try saving it like : `Application.Current.Properties.Add("1", whoIs);` and to access it `: Application.Current.Properties["1"]);`

Comment: Still cant read it in another Window. Count is 0. Maybe there is another way?